# Call vba code when button in userform is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the following simple `UserForm1` containing `CommandButton1 = Yes` and `CommandButton2 = No`:

[image]

I call this `UserForm1` with the following VBA:

```
Sub Open_Userform()
Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

Now I want that if the user clicks on `CommandButton1` the following VBA is called:

```
Sub Finish_Process()
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

Therefore, I added the following code in the `UserForm1` to the `CommandButton1`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Finish_Process
End Sub
```

However, now when I click on `CommandButton1` I get error `Sub or Function not defined`.

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: Is `Finish_Process` Macro in Another Workbook ?

Comment: It is in "This Worksheet"

Comment: Can you add that in a Module & Try again ? Though it should work in `This Worksheet`

Comment: Try changing `Sub Finish_Process()` to `Public Sub Finish_Process()`

Comment: Put it in a normal module.

Comment: Agree with everyone else. Sub `Finish_Process()` needs to be in a regular module not the worksheet. +1 for a very well forumlated question.

Comment: So when I want to go back from a UserForm to a normal VBA code it always has to be stored in a module?

Comment: If you don't want the code in a normal module it can be stored in the userform code module instead and should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comments the issue can be solved if the `Sub Finish_Process ()` is stored in a module and not within "This Worksheet".